# Upload large files to AWS bucket in chuncks using Java and OkHttpClient

Tags: java, okhttp

I need to upload large files to an AWS bucket using Java and OkHttpClient3.

I'm able to upload files in a single chunk and all works well. However, I need to do it in multiple chunks, for example chunks of 500mb. How do I partially send pieces of a file?

This works well for a single chunck...

```
import okhttp3.*;

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .connectTimeout(2400, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(2400, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(2400, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("Content-Type", _responseInit.getMultipart_params().getContentType())
        .addFormDataPart("Policy", _responseInit.getMultipart_params().getPolicy())
        .addFormDataPart("X-Amz-Signature", _responseInit.getMultipart_params().getXamzSignature())
        .addFormDataPart("acl", _responseInit.getMultipart_params().getAcl())
        .addFormDataPart("key", _responseInit.getMultipart_params().getKey() + "/p1")
        .addFormDataPart("success_action_status", _responseInit.getMultipart_params().getSuccess_action_status())
        .addFormDataPart("x-amz-algorithm", _responseInit.getMultipart_params().getXamzAlgorithm())
        .addFormDataPart("x-amz-credential", _responseInit.getMultipart_params().getXamzCredential())
        .addFormDataPart("x-amz-date", _responseInit.getMultipart_params().getXamzDate())
        .addFormDataPart("name", _asset.getName())
        .addFormDataPart("chunk", "1")
        .addFormDataPart("chunks", "1")
        .addFormDataPart("Filename", _responseInit.getMultipart_params().getKey() + "/p1")
        .addFormDataPart("file", _asset.getName(),
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), _asset))
        .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(_endPoint)
        .method("POST", body)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
        .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

After each upload of a chunk, I need to register the chunk. So I need to call this code multiple times ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Use a byte array to read the file in chunks, then pass the byte array as argument to the client object ...

```
    int filePosition = 0;
    long currentPosition = 0;
    
    String partSize = "104857600"; // Chuncks of 100 MB.
    Integer partSizeInt = Integer.valueOf(partSize);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[partSizeInt ];
    FileInputStream fileToUpload = null;
    
    File myFile = new File("FULL PATH TO FILE");


    try {
        fileToUpload = new FileInputStream(myFile);

        int read = 0;

        while (currentPosition < myFile.length())
        {
            read = fileToUpload.read(buffer, filePosition, buffer.length);

            if (read == -1) {
                break;
            }else{
                byte[] bytesRead = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, read);

                ...

                .addFormDataPart("file", _asset.getName(),
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), bytesRead ))

                ...

                currentPosition = currentPosition + read;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // crap
    } finally {
        try {
            fileToUpload.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```